# Angular $http POST cannot get response when 400 bad request

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, http-post, http-status-code-400

The front end code POST the user credential to the back end and if the credential is invalid then the back end server responses with **400 bad request** and a response data below

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid username or password"
}
```

I am seeing this response in network tab in the browser and also in postman chrome app.

For some reason, I am not able to get this response or catch error or status of the error. Please find my code snippets below

```
newLoginAuth: function(credentials) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    url: 'https://myserver.com/api/connect/token',
      method: "POST",
      data: { 
        'username': credentials.username,
        'password': credentials.password,
        'clientId': 'clientId',
        'clientSecret': 'Y2xpZW50U2VjcmV0'
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' },

      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      }, function(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }


myService.newLoginAuth({username: self.userName, password: self.password})
          .then((result) => {

             console.log(result); //undefined
          });
```

Can someone help me? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: why are you using `$q.defer();` when clearly `$http(` returns a Promise

Comment: If the request is cross origin, it may be just like a question yesterday, where the API involved only issues CORS headers on http status 200 - any other status (403 in the other question), and the API didn't send any CORS headers, making the response not available to the request - and the http status resulting in `0` - i.e. more code monkeys not knowing how to write a useful API

Comment: @JaromandaX Understood your second comment. Could you please elaborate and provide me the correct way if there is anything wrong in my code snippet?

Comment: from what you've posted, the problem is with the API - at your end, you can test for http status of `0` to indicate an error - you just wont get any useful error responses from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object has these properties:

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

if(response.status == 400) alert('Bad Request');
```

Comment: I am getting response as undefined that is the issue